# Valve/Filter allowing through gas only, no liquid

Tags: fluid-mechanics, gas, multiphase-flow

I need to devise a way to ensure only NG passes through a pipe, and no condensates or other liquids. It is ok to shut down the pipeline if liquids would be detected. The dimensions involved are small and space limited.

Is there a valve which shuts if liquid starts passing through but stays open for gas? Aside from a involved solution with a trap with a sensor attached, is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: A ball valve? The ball floats on the liquid and closes the valve if the level is too high...

Comment: Have you looked into if there is a material that is highly selective for NG that can be made into a cartridge filter? Maybe start with a vendor like Parker?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! The ball valve seems workable as a concept I'll have a look if I can find a ready product.
I'll also give Parker a call and see if they have smth on the shelf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you searching for is called:

**Thermostatic expansion valve or (TXV).**

You have one of those in your air conditioner. Because the compressor of AC's are designed to handel only vapour.

Comment: Thank you, this is very close. I'd need a TXV tuned for NG phase diagram but now I have a working principle!